# MySQL update query with 'concat()' value based on a 'CASE' not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the a column value by appending a string to itself based on if the column value doesn't already have it. I thought I had it right but am unable to get it to work. Can someone help me understand if I am heading in a wrong direction. I would also appreciate if you could show me if there is a better way of doing this.

use `my_database`;

```
$additional_condition = 'string with special chars and quotes';

update my_table set my_column = concat(my_column, CASE WHEN my_column LIKE '%$additional_condition%' THEN $additional_condition ELSE '' END) where my_name in ('x', 'y');
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Why have you tagged the question with MySQL and PL/SQL (the latter is associated with Oracle DB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should move the condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
update my_table
    set my_column = concat(my_column, $additional_condition)
    where my_name in ('x', 'y') and
          my_column not like '%$additional_condition%';
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon moving the condition is a good idea. The problem didn't go away by doing so though. The problem is with using the column with it's name alone {my_column} using it with table name fixed it {my_table .my_column} . Hope it helps anyone going through the same issue.